# C variable showing different different Value

Tags: c

I was getting some unexpected behavior in one of my program. After further analysis i found some strange result in the below shortened code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
     int k = 0;
     int rstr[200];
     printf("value of  k= %d\n",k);
     printf("adress of k = %x\n",&k);
     printf("adress of rstr[0] = %x\n",&rstr[0]);
     printf("adress of rstr[199] = %x\n",&rstr[199]);


     rstr[200] = " ";
     printf("value of  k= %d\n",k);
     printf("adress of k = %x\n",&k);
     printf("adress of rstr[200] = %x\n",&rstr[200]);
     return 0;
   }
```

rstr[200] is out of size so it will contain garbage value,but, how it is passing to variable k. Please answer.[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NHx5.png)

Comment: Undefined. Behavior.

Comment: your question would be better with the output as text, not as image.

Comment: Use `%p` to print pointer values: `printf( "address of k = %p\n", (void *) &k );`. This pretty much the only place you need to explicitly cast a ponter value to `void *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `rstr[200]` is out of size so it will contain garbage value

No, accessing `rstr[200]` doesn't mean you'll get garbage values. It's not something a compliant program is allowed to do, ever. An out of bounds array access results in your program having undefined behavior. You can observe *anything*.

In your particular case, the compiler is placing `k` *immediately after* the array `rstr` in memory. So modifying `rstr[200]` ends up messing with `k`.

Answer (score 1):

`&rstr[200]` is out of `rstr` array. So accessing this address is theorically invalid (undefined behaviour), while printing it is okay (as long as you use `%p` as format, for *pointers*)

In your case, it seems that the compiler has put `rstr` first then `k` in the auto variable allocation area, which explain both addresses match (and in that case `rstr[200]` does *not* contain garbage value but the value of `k`

of course, don't rely on that... It's just to give an explanation (well, some hackers use this technique, known as *buffer overflow*, to make program crash (*DOS attack*) or even take control of the program by changing the return address to point to injected code).

(also note that `rstr[200] = " ";` is also undefined whatever the size of `rstr` is: assigning a pointer on literal in an array of `int` doesn't work too well...)

Answer (score 0):

These are the following errors I noticed when compiled:

```
 prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:11:16: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
      rstr[200] = " ";
                ^
prog.c:11:10: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
      rstr[200] = " ";
      ~~~~^~~~~
```

1. **Access out of bounds** is an undefined behavior and it may produce unexpected outputs.
2. According to C11-ISO standards :

   > If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.

Therefore, always use `%p` to print a pointer address with cast to `void*` to the argument.

For ex:

```
printf("adress of k = %p\n",(void*)&k);
```

About the undefined behavior :

> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements

BONUS: always use the latest compilers with flags -Wall -O2 -pedantic-errors enabled to see all the warnings.